# Rack throwing an error when trying to serve a static file

Tags: ruby, rack

```
use Rack::Static, :urls => ['/stylesheets', '/images'], :root => 'public'

run proc { |env| [200, { 'Content-Type' => 'text/html', 'Cache-Control' => 'public, max-age=86400' }, File.open('public/index.html')] }
```

I get private method `open' called for Rack::File:Class when I rackup.  Really can't see where the problem is. Running rack 1.1. Help please...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a `Rack::File` class,  which has precedence in your rackup file because of the way Ruby looks up names. This is not the class you are looking for, you want Ruby's own `File` class. That class can be referenced directly without lookup ambiguity by using the prefix `::`

```
::File.open('public/index.html')
```